# Fragment fadeout on horizontal swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, ontouchlistener

In my game I have a `Fragment` in fullscreen that pops to indicate which player have to play.

The player must swipe the `Fragment` horizontaly more than half screen (left or right), so he could play..

Here's my `Fragment` code:

```
public class PopPlayerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener{
[...]
private float mMaxSlide;
private float mInitialMotionX;
private float mActualMotionX;
private float mLastMotionX;
[...]
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, [...]){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pfragment, container, false);
    mMaxSlide = getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                .getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
    [...]
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mInitialMotionX = event.getX();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mActualMotionX = event.getX();
            final float dx = mActualMotionX - mInitialMotionX;
            final float adx = Math.abs(dx);
            v.setX(v.getX() + dx);
            if(adx <= mMaxSlide)
                v.setAlpha(1.0f - (adx / mMaxSlide));
            else
                v.setAlpha(0.0f);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mLastMotionX = event.getX();
            final float adxup = Math.abs(mLastMotionX - mInitialMotionX);
            if(adxup >= mMaxSlide){
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(this).commit();
            } else{
                v.setX(0.0f);
                v.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }
            return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

I want to move the `Fragment` the same way as I move my finger and I want it to fade from 1 to 0.

For example, on a 800px width device, **mMaxSlide** = 400, so when I touch the screen the `Fragment`'s alpha is 1.0, when I swipe 200px it should get alpha = 0.5 and so on..

When the `Frgament` has moved more than **mMaxSlide** I hide it, otherwise it comes back to his initial position with full opacity.

The problem is that when I test this:

- the right swiping is ok as the `Fragment` moves with my finger but never fade out (except if I swipe very fast) and always come back to the initial position..
- the left swiping doesn't work at all, a little move cause the `Fragment` to slide far away because **mActualMotionX** drastically increases..

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question :

If I don't move the `Fragment` while touching, the fadeout works, so I had to move only a part of my layout, to keep still the one which is listening.

My layout is composed of a `FrameLayout` in fullscreen with a `RelativeLayout` in it so the listener is set to the `FrameLayout` and only the `RelativeLayout` with his childs move and fade as wished :p